# Failed to bind Spring Boot port on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application on Heroku with Docker. The build is successful both when building the .war file and the Docker image. I'm not entirely sure where the problem exists.

I have tried defining `EXPOSE 80`, `ENV PORT=80` in my Dockerfile and that doesn't work either. I tried defining the port in my config file **application-prod.yml**, but that didn't work. What else should I look for here, is there something I missed with deploying on Heroku with Spring Boot?

**The error message:**

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
> 60 seconds of launch

This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM tomcat:jdk16-openjdk-slim

# Java options
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xms100M -Xmx100M -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dserver.port=80"
ENV PORT=80

# Firebase Config
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./src/main/resources/firebase.json

# War file for Tomcat
ARG WAR_FILE=/build/libs/mefit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ${WAR_FILE} /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms100M -Xmx100M"
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

**This is the log from Heroku:**

```
021-09-20T12:34:35.702071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `catalina.sh run`
2021-09-20T12:34:36.462169+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:36.463899+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms100M -Xmx100M -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dserver.port=80
2021-09-20T12:34:36.886149+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.877 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.11
2021-09-20T12:34:36.886476+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 6 2021 16:22:12 UTC
2021-09-20T12:34:36.886714+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.11.0
2021-09-20T12:34:36.886938+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.886 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
2021-09-20T12:34:36.887167+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-1095-aws
2021-09-20T12:34:36.887411+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
2021-09-20T12:34:36.887620+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk-16
2021-09-20T12:34:36.887812+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           16.0.2+7-67
2021-09-20T12:34:36.888037+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.887 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
2021-09-20T12:34:36.888247+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
2021-09-20T12:34:36.888451+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:36.888 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289288+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms100M
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289384+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx100M
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289485+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289594+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dserver.port=80
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289689+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289786+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289879+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:37.289965+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290048+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290139+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290224+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290296+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290385+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290466+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290546+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms100M
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290662+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx100M
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290743+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290827+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290905+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
2021-09-20T12:34:37.290985+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
2021-09-20T12:34:37.294694+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.294 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
2021-09-20T12:34:37.294793+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.294 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
2021-09-20T12:34:37.297476+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:37.297 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021]
2021-09-20T12:34:38.320649+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:38.320 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-09-20T12:34:38.344458+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:38.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1669] milliseconds
2021-09-20T12:34:38.397136+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:38.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
2021-09-20T12:34:38.397311+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:38.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.11]
2021-09-20T12:34:38.411783+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:38.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
2021-09-20T12:34:49.601670+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:49.601 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-09-20T12:34:49.668340+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:49.668 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [11,256] ms
2021-09-20T12:34:49.677006+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:49.676 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-09-20T12:34:49.688535+00:00 app[web.1]: 20-Sep-2021 12:34:49.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [11342] milliseconds
2021-09-20T12:35:35.854246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-09-20T12:35:35.943021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-09-20T12:35:36.135780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-09-20T12:35:36.414530+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**This is how I deployed my application with Heroku CLI:**

```
heroku container:push web --app my-app-name
heroku container:release web --app my-app-name
```

**This is the application-prod.yml file that I'm using:**

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
  datasource:
    url: ${URL}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /v1/docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /v1/docs/index.html
    operationsSorter: method

security:
  firebase-props:
    database-url: ${FIREBASE_DB_URL}
    enable-strict-server-session: false
    enable-check-session-revoked: false
    enable-logout-everywhere: false
    session-expiry-in-days: 5
  cookie-props:
    max-age-in-minutes: 7200
    http-only: true
    secure: false
    domain: localhost
    path: /
  allow-credentials: true
  allowed-origins:
    - http://localhost:4200
  allowed-methods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - PUT
    - PATCH
    - DELETE
    - OPTIONS
  allowed-headers:
    - Authorization
    - Origin
    - Content-Type
    - Accept
    - Accept-Encoding
    - Accept-Language
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    - Access-Control-Request-Method
    - X-Requested-With
    - X-Auth-Token
    - X-Xsrf-Token
    - Cache-Control
    - Id-Token
  exposed-headers:
    - X-Xsrf-Token
  allowed-public-apis:
    - /favicon.ico
    - /session/login
    - /public/*
    - /test/**

logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    org:
      springframework:
        web: DEBUG
      hibernate: ERROR
  pattern:
    console: "%d{HH:mm:ss} || %highlight(%5p) < %highlight(%-35.35logger{35}) > %highlight(%m%n)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show my your Spring boot propertie files? I would like to see if you tell spring boot that its' hosting port is depending on an environment variable.

Comment: I updated the question with the requested file.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I think you are missing the server port option in your properties. This property will tell spring boot on what port to "host"' your application (for a more clear ref: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port)). What you should do, is add this property and bind it to `"${PORT}:8080"`. This will make sure that it looks for the value of the 'PORT' environment variable and when it cannot find this value, it will use 8080 as a backup (please replace 8080) with whatever value fits your need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Alexander, but it did unfortunately not work. I also use the flag `-Dserver.port=$PORT` in the java tool options in my **Dockerfile** that should do the same thing, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, sorry for looking over that... However, what I think is happening, is that Heroku wants to define the port it is hosting on. With your setup, you leave it no option but to bind it to port 80. I feel leek you should try hosting on Heroku first (without docker). I've done that a few times already by connecting my repo directly to Heroku without any issues. I think setting the PORT env in your dockerfile is not the correct play.